# WS nodejs websockets how to make a the receiving client

Tags: node.js, ws

Hello I am trying to learn how to connect a server to a website page. I have made my server in node.js and attempted to use the ws library. I'm not sure what to do on the client side. On the documentation page on ws (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#simple-server) it says I have to use "require" to import ws, however i'm assuming that you need to use node.js to use a "require" statement which I am not on my client.

Any tips or links to information is appreciated

```
// Server

const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const path = require('path');

const server = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'cert.pem')),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem'))
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server})
console.log(server)
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

    ws.send('something');
});

server.listen(443, function () {
    console.log('Server is listening on 443');
});
```

```
// html page --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        const ws = new WebSocket("wss://websiteName.com");

        ws.on('open', function open() {
            ws.send('something');
        });

        ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: At first blush, your client-side code looks fine to me.  webSocket support is built into the browser so you don't need an external library for a plain webSocket connection from a browser webpage.  You would use `require()` if you were coding a webSocket client from nodejs.  What specific problem or error do you observe or want help with?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jfriend00.
I have uploaded the html file on namecheap/cpanel who is hosting my website. I want to make a connection from my server to the client. When I start my node js server and try to go on my website page it says "Uncaught TypeError: ws.on is not a function" and "WebSocket connection to "wss//websiteName.com/ failed:" on the console

Comment: It looks like `.on()` is not a supported method.  You would use `ws.addEventListener('open', ...)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks I no longer get the "Uncaught TypeError: ws.on is not a function" message. However I still get "wss://websiteName.com/ failed:" on google chrome and "WebSocket connection to "wss://websiteName.com/" failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404" on microsoft edge.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your websocket server is up and running and reachable at your domain?  You can run a simple test on your server here: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html by entering your host name there.  If you share your actual hostname, then we could try it out too.

Comment: @jfriend00 It doesn't seem to work with my own host name. It is https://detbaredejligt.com by the way. I really appreciate your time :).

Comment: Where is your server running?  Is it available to the general internet?  I can ping a host at that domain, but can't connect to it via websocket or https.

Comment: @jfriend00 the website is running on namecheap/cpanel and the server is running on node.js in a vs code terminal

Comment: @jfriend00 according to this link: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9705/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-nodejs/#https_node_js
hostname is used inside of the listen() method. However, when i try to, i get a message in my terminal saying "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.64.118.23:443"

Comment: I don't know - it's likely some sort of issue with how you initialize your server in that hosting company's environment to make it work properly.  I see on namecheap's site that only some hosting plans support websockets.  What type of hosting plan are you running your server on?  Are you sure that hosting plan supports websockets?  If "vs code terminal" means visual studio terminal, try running it in a regular terminal.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using the stellar shared hosting. After reading your comment searching a bit on google, i found 2 people commenting that namecheap's shared hosting won't work with websockets. I contacted the customer service and they told me they can't open port 443. From what i'm gathering, I may need to use a vps (virtual private server)?

Comment: I guess that would explain it, then.  It is not uncommon that webSockets require a higher level of hosting plan, partly because they are continuous connections which aren't as friendly to widely shared hosting.

Comment: @jfriend00 I really can't thank you enough :)